# Using knowledge of derivatives, what is $f(x)$ if $f'(x) = 4x + e^x$ with initial condition $f(0)=2$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to solve this with knowledge of derivatives? Is it asking to solve this without using anti-derivatives?

Comment: I think it is asking to solve it using known anti-derivatives of the components of $f'$

Comment: You need anti-derivatives by definition to solve this.

Comment: I just completed a chapter on derivatives but did not get to anti-derivatives yet. So if problems asks to use knowledge of derivatives, I was thinking that there was another way to solve this kind of problems without knowing anti-derivatives yet.

Comment: I guess the only way without antiderivatives is by the maclaurin series expansion of $e^x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely need antiderivatives here. You have to find the antiderivative of the function $f'(x)$ which will give you a family of functions that differ only by a constant. One of those functions is going to be the function you're looking for. Then, use the initial condition that you're given ($f(0)=2$) to determine the consonant of integration you get when you're done integrating $f'(x)$.

$$
f(x)=\int\left(4x+e^x\right)\,dx=2x^2+e^x+C,\\
f(0)=2\cdot0^2+e^0+C=2\implies
C=1.\\
\therefore\ f(x)=2x^2+e^x+1.
$$

Comment: Thank you sir for your clear explanation. I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

Integrate both sides to get $f(x)$ and the equation becomes

$$f(x) = 2x^2 + e^x + c.$$

Put $x=0$ and $f(x=0)=2$ to get $c=1$. Substitute the value of $c$ and get

$$f(x)=2x^2+e^x+1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is the intention of the exercise: because $f'(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ then $f(x)=G(x)+H(x)+C$ for some constant $C$ where $G$ and $H$ are antiderivatives of $g$ and $h$ respectively.

I mean: "knowledge of derivatives" seems to me to search for such $G$ and $H$ with derivatives $g$ and $h$, knowing that if $f(x)=G(x)+H(x)+C$ then $f'(x)=g(x)+h(x)$.

Then for any valid pair $G$ and $H$ the constant $C$ is defined by the value $f(0)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

The *First  Fundametal Theorem of Integral Calculus* asserts that the antiderivative of $4x+\mathrm e^x$ which takes the value $2$ at $x=0$ is the function
$$f(x)=2+\int_0^x(4tx+\mathrm e^t)\,\mathrm dt.$$
(The integral from $0$ is the antiderivative which vanishes at $x=0$).